# Show form from php file on one of my pages - how?

Tags: php, jquery, html, contact-form, ticket-system

I've spend a week on this issue and it is probably real simple...

I am using osTicket (open source support ticket system) on my site. I want to use the ticketform as a contact form on one of my pages. I only want to show the form id="ticketForm" (see code below) because I don't want all the rest of the code (menu with Support Center Home, Open New Ticket, Check Ticket Status buttons etc.) from the open.php file - I tried to use an iframe, but too many problems and iframe is not a good way to do it.

I want to use this part (I don't show all the code because I think there is some sensitive information in the code - hope that is okay):

```
<form id="ticketForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="open.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" value=......... etc. code for name, email, attachment fields, captcha etc.</form>
```

from:
www.mysite.com...../support/open.php

and show it on: 
www.mysite.com...../contact.html

so that I get a contact form that blends in with the text I have on that page.

Any simple way to do this? Please be gentle (don't assume that I know things that you take for granted) - I'm no coder :o) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `contact.html` do the following:

```
$('#result').load('/path/to/open.php #ticketForm');
```

that will retrieve the form with id `ticketForm` from open.php and place it inside the div with id `result` in your contact.html page.

See the [**Loading page fragments**](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) section of `.load()` jquery method.

**UPDATE:**
You should put the above code in the document.ready handler inside the `<body>` of your contact.html, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#result').load('/path/to/open.php #ticketForm');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I have actually tried that one, but it doesn't seem to do a thing. Maybe it is because it is a local site I'm working on? (sorry I should have said that, but all other local sites work fine). I use Wampserver.

In my contact.html page I have placed this in the head:

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
$('#result').load('http://localhost/support/open.php #ticketForm');
</script>

and this in body:

<div id="result"></div>

I tried the physical address "file:///C:/wamp/www/support/open.php" but nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: You must put the code of my answer in the BODY not the HEAD, also in de .ready handler, see the update of my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Strange, I tested the code on another site that is online and it worked after I inserted <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in the head. BUT it still doesn't work on my local testsite and that is a problem for me - firebug gives me this error "TypeError: $ is not a function" for the line with "$(document).ready(function() {".

What is wrong? Website is on "file:///C:/....." and osTicket is on "http://localhost/" - same computer but... is it something about the same-origin policy or is it the wampserver??

Comment: It seems you don't have internet access in your local testsite, that's why it can't retrieve ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js and so the error you get, just download from a pc with internet access and put it in the same directory as your html file and include it in HEAD as <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: My computer has internet access so that isn't the problem. I found out what the problem is, and it was the problem I suggested - the same-origin policy. I inserted this in my php file "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');" right after "<?php" and then it worked (I just have to remember to remove it before my site goes live). Sure I will accept your answer because you have been helpful - thanks for your help ;o)

Comment: I found out that the load function doesn't pass the information back when a user presses the "send" button. It only shows the form. I thought it worked like an iframe... it doesn't! I need another solution.